# X-Frame-Option header and cascading iframes

Tags: iframe, x-frame-options

I have a UI scenario where there are two iframes. One iframe has another iframe and both show content from same domain (say DOMAIN_1). The outer iframe is hosted is a webpage for other domain (say DOMAIN_2).

In Summary, I have

> Webpage of DOMAIN_2 that hosts
>
> > > Iframe (Outer) of DOMAIN_1 that hosts
> > >
> > > > > Iframe (Inner) of DOMAIN_1.

Question: I have not set X-Frame-Option header for Outer Iframe and it works as expected from DOMAIN_2 webpage. What value should I set for X-Frame-Option header for inner iframe? I tried setting it to SAMEORIGIN since inner iframe and outer iframe have same domain, but this did not worked. Is this expected?